# Trouble designing and saving layout with checkboxes programatically

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I'm a beginner android developer. I am creating an app but having trouble to get a rough outline for my next task which I am going to explain below. I am not asking for code. I just want to know the best way to do the below.

I have an `Activity` that displays a `RecyclerView` with a list of items like this:

[image]

My question is related to the 3 checkboxes.

- How should I approach creating the layout in the pic? Do I have to include 3 checkboxes and 3 booleans in my main object class? The other items in the object class are saved in SQL database and the `RecyclerView` in the activity gets its data from there using a `cursor`. Can the value of the checkboxes be retrieved using the cursor?
- Do I create a separate `sparseBooleanArray` for the checkboxes? Do I create a `HashMap` for them?
- Should I store the value of the checkboxes (Checked/Not Checked) in SQL or `SharedPreferences`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically an opinion based question and hence I am throwing some suggestions on how you should implement it. If I have understood your problem correctly, you have provided a single list item in your `RecyclerView` and the items are being populated from a local sqlite database table.

Hence there are three checkboxes for each of the list item and yes, of course you need to save the states of the checkboxes in your sqlite table along with the information of the list item. I do not know about your current table structure. However, the pseudo implementation of your updated table structure may look something like the following.

```
item_id    description    checked_status
----------------------------------------
1          Some desc      null (Not checked)
2          Some desc      LOCK
3          Some desc      DONE
4          Some desc      NOTIFY_ME
```

Hence when you are clicking on your checkbox, you need to update the sqlite table accordingly with the newly updated data for that specific row and update the `RecyclerView` items accordingly.